# Create static electricity from batteries

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, voltage

I have to demonstrate a simple DIY electroscope.

[image: electroscope]

For this I need to create a source of static electricity using household materials. The weather at my place is very humid. So all my efforts of creating static electricity by triboelectric effect (rubbing for e.g. PVC pipe against silk/fur/wool, comb against hair/silk/fur/wool, vinyl against silk/fur/wool, balloon against silk/fur/wool) goes futile. The charge developed is nil to very less. I can see the electroscope work 1 out ot 10 times, that too not visually significant. Is there someway I could create some amount of static electricity using ordinary batteries?

PS: I am not looking for huge amounts of static electricity like in [electrostatic generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_generator)

Comment: If you want to stick to "classic" experiments with a mechanical electroscope, then you may have to lower the humidity of your materials by desiccating them. A modern JFET or CMOS opamp is the best low voltage electroscope you can imagine. Basically all the classical experiments can be done easily with such a device at low voltages. And, no, there is absolutely nothing wrong with using an electronic device to produce high voltage, either. It has been done in high school setups for many decades.

Comment: Maybe this will work for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_water_dropper

Answer (score 1):

The possible problem is that static electric charges tend to have very high voltage, though tiny amounts numbers of electrons. Consider how long a spark you can get from a comb in dry air, compared to the length of spark from 110 volt wires.

So it depends on how small a voltage your electroscope can detect. You don't need strong batteries, but you might need a lot of volts.

Ten 9-volt batteries in series will get you close to 90 volts. That might be enough. Or if your electroscope is sensitive, maybe even fewer.

The comment by @SolomonSlow suggests that 90 volts is unlikely to be enough. So it might work better to use a [voltage multiplier](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-3/voltage-multipliers/) to get hundreds or thousands of low-amperage volts. At this point the project to test the electroscope looks considerably more complex than the project to build the electroscope.

I vaguely remember reading about somebody who gave static electricity demonstrations who had the problem that sometimes the air was too humid. So he developed some ways to temporarily get dryer air around his experiment. But I don't remember exactly what he did. It involved some sort of aerosol can.

Maybe you could wave some dry ice around your electroscope, and the low temperature might condense moisture out of the air?

Comment: I would suggest to include the use of a large series resistor with a 90V battery setup. While not outrageously dangerous, 90V DC can and will hurt if touched without any current limiting. A 1MOhm resistor will prevent unpleasant accidents. As a general principle one should always limit currents that humans can be exposed to 100uA or less.

Comment: @FlatterMann I don't know if it's enough for human safety in all cases, but 10 9-V batteries (which is 60 1.5 V cells) in series will provide some pretty substantial current limiting. Of course you wouldn't want to charge up a big capacitor with this contraption and then grab the terminals.

Comment: @ThePhoton Short circuit current for a fresh 9V battery can be several A, more than enough to give somebody a bad day if they short ten of them in series. My general motto with regards to high voltage sources (>40V) is that a series resistor a day keeps the doctor away. Disregard at your own peril, but you will never find a circuit of mine that does not have some form of current and power limiting.

Comment: So, I just hold the positive end of the 90V battery (Ten 9V batteries in series) near the copper wire of the electroscope?

Comment: You might also want to connect the other end of the battery to Earth (e.g., to a water pipe.) But don't count on it actually working. The [Wikipedia article on Electroscopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroscope) suggests that 90V might not be enough. It suggests that you will need somewhere between multiple hundreds of Volts and thousands of Volts.

Comment: @SolomonSlow A good electroscope is much more sensitive than that. See e.g. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14786443309462331?journalCode=tphm18 Having said that, the folks who were building these had decades of experience with the design. I would go with an electronic amplifier for a few dollars anytime instead.

Answer (score 0):

In this video, the demostrator is using a 6000 Volts DC power supply to charge a small metal sphere by touching the positive terminal to the the metal held with an insulated stick.

I too was racking my brain for a long time with this question - a convenient source of static electricity without all that rubbing. But a 6K Volts DC eliminator is not something one finds lying around...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaBW6DCy1Zo